# Is there a built-in function to generate multiple paragraph tags based on a string with new line separators?

Tags: php, functions

Consider the following code

```php
<?php

// The new line separated string
$section_string = <<<EOL
Sentence A1. Sentence A2. Sentence A3.

Sentence B1. Sentence B2. Sentence B3.

Sentence C1. Sentence C2. Sentence C3.
EOL;

// Is there a function you can call like so:
$html_markup = unknown_awesome_function( $section_string );

echo $html_markup;

?>
```

Expected output

```html
<p>Sentence A1. Sentence A2. Sentence A3.</p><p>Sentence B1. Sentence B2. Sentence B3.</p><p>Sentence C1. Sentence C2. Sentence C3.</p>
```

Instead of the example fictional `unknown_awesome_function()`, is there a built-in function you can call to generate multiple `<p>` tags based on a string with new line separators?

Comment: Have you tried `apply_filters('the_content', $section_string)`? That should apply `wp_autop` which would add either `<p>` tags or `<br>`s.

Comment: @WebElaine that worked like a charm! Exactly what was needed. It added the `<p>` tag, not the `<br>`. Would you mind posting it as an answer? I'd like to give you some bounty for the awesome response. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `apply_filters('the_content', $section_string)`? That should apply wp_autop which would add either `<p>` tags or `<br>`s.